# How to get all revisions document with single request in couchdb?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I use nano.js as couchdb driver in my express app. i managed to get document revision's id with command like this

```
db.get(id, { revs_info: true }, function(err, inventory){
  res.send(inventory);
})
```

which returns the latest revisions with _revs_info in it. Unfortunately _rev_info only includes revision number and availability status.

```
{ _id: 'doc',
 _rev: '3-825cb35de44c433bfb2df415563a19de',
 _revs_info: 
    [ { rev: '3-825cb35de44c433bfb2df415563a19de',
        status: 'available' },
      { rev: '2-7051cbe5c8faecd085a3fa619e6e6337',
        status: 'available' },
      { rev: '1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d',
        status: 'available' } ] 
}
```

so how to get all revision's document with single request in couchdb ?